# Trying to drop trigger I created in pgadminIII but not dropping

Tags: sql, triggers, schema, pgadmin

I created a trigger called 'check_totalc' in a public schema

I tried:
DROP TRIGGER public.check_totalc;

but it doesn't work.
I have many triggers that I need to drop but I can't seem to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this in the end, for anyone in the future who may be struggling I used:

`DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS check_totalc() CASCADE;`